# Setting background to cover whole screen when using aspect Fit in Swift

Tags: swift, background

When using aspect fit in swift, the sides of the screen are removed. Is there a way I can cover this up by using a background colour to fill the whole screen or use a background image?

Here is the code for creating the scene as aspect fit in the GameViewController

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "mainMenu") {


//                setting scene here to aspect fit

                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit

//                 Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene)
            }

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
```

[scene with aspect fit and background set to clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUnUt.png)

[scene with aspect fill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvXAn.png)

[scene with aspect fit and background set to green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya4my.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the screen size for the scene.

```
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
scene?.size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
```

After, set `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill`

If this doesn’t work, you can try and set the background color by doing this, but I’m unaware if this option will give you what you’re looking for as I didn’t test it.

```
scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white //color you want
```

Otherwise try setting `scene?.size = image.size`

Comment: thanks for such a speedy response! The reason I am using aspect fit is because when I used aspect fill the screen stretched way out of view when I used it on an iPad as opposed to a phone. I will try attach an image now to explain this. Cheers again!

Comment: @Bushers Did you try setting the screen size as suggested?

Comment: I tried setting the screen size and it had the same effect as aspect fill would.

Comment: @Bushers set the screen size with the aspectFill option. Also post picture when you get it

Comment: will get back to you in just a minute, just having a few technical issues

Comment: Now, what is your desired outcome? It seems to me that aspectFill fills the screen correctly.

Comment: if you look at the image of aspect fill you will see that it cuts off the top of the screen relative to the aspect fit. The desired outcome is that I can set the whole screen background colour whilst still keeping the screen image appearing as the aspect fit does

Comment: Did you try scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white (or your desired color)?

Comment: yep, if you look at the third image I attached. The image shows what happens when I do this as the program understands the screen to be of different dimensions to the actual screen size - if that makes sense??

Comment: For your third case, this is happening because you are using aspectFit. This is ensuring that your whole image is portrayed into the scene correctly. Without being able to see your code, my last suggestion would be to set scene?.size = image.size